# Converting element in char array to int

Tags: c++, arrays, char

I have an 80 element `char` array and I am trying to specific elements to an `integer` and am getting some number errors.
Array element 40 in hex is **0xC0**. When I try assigning it to an `integer` I get in hex **0xFFFFC0**, and I dont know why.

```
char tempArray[80]; //Read in from file, with element 40 as 0xC0
int tempInt = (int)tempArray[40]; //Output as 0xFFFFC0 instead of 0x0000C0
```

Comment: Because  ``0XC0`` is negative in ``char``, and the cast is preserving the sign as an ``int``.

Comment: `int tempInt = (int)tempArray[40];` --> `unsigned tempInt = (unsigned)tempArray[40];` will do the trick.

Answer (score 14):

**Depending on your implementation**, a `char` type in C++ is **either** a `signed` type **or** an `unsigned` type. (The C++ standard mandates that an implementation chooses either scheme).

To be on the safe side, use `unsigned char` in your case.

Comment: Up-vote for you, I forgot about the fact that it could be platform dependent.

Answer (score 3):

This is so because `char` is treated as signed number, and the promotion to `int` preserves the sign. Change the array from `char` to `unsigned char` to avoid it.

Answer (score 3):

Because  `0XC0` is negative in `char`, and the cast is preserving the sign as an `int`. You should use `unsigned char` if you want to maintain the directly binary translation or as a purely positive value

Answer (score 1):

for more convenience, I always use `unsigned` and `signed` always before declaration and casting. you can write the following:

```
unsigned char tempArray[80]; //Read in from file, with element 40 as 0xC0
unsigned int tempInt = (unsigned int)tempArray[40]; //Output as 0xFFFFC0 instead of 0x0000C0
```

Comment: Your cast is unnecessary and the output is 0xC0 not 0xFFFFC0

Comment: It well might be. but this kind of casting makes the code more readable.

Answer (score 0):

`char` may be signed, so converting from a negative `char` value will result in a negative `int` value, which is usualyl represented in two's complement, resulting in a very high binary representation.

Instead, either use `int tempInt = 0xFF & tempArray[40]`, define tempArray as `unsigned char`, or cast to `unsigned char` : `int tempInt = (unsigned char)tempArray[40]` (unsure if this is defined behaviour).